# Issue in executing Spring Web project in Eclipse on Tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven-2, spring-mvc, m2eclipse

I have a Spring web project that uses Maven to compile/build. There is no issue in building the project. I am trying to run the project in Eclipse (3.3.2) on Tomcat (v6) server.

As part of Spring project, I have a spring-servlet.xml file in WEB-INF directory. This file includes another resource xml file that has datasource configuration.

```
<import resource="classpath:${datasourceInclude}.xml"/>
```

Now when the project is compiled using Maven, it resolves the variable ${datasourceInclude} and set it with appropriate values resulting in spring-servlet.xml with proper values.

```
<import resource="classpath:datasourceLocal.xml"/>
```

But when I tried running the project in Eclipse (Tomcat), I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:${datasourceInclude}.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [${datasourceInclude}.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [${datasourceInclude}.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
...
...
```

Basically when I starts Tomcat, it tries to pick the spring-servlet.xml from /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder which has ${datasourceInclude} variable.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue so that I dont have to change spring-servlet.xml and add hard code value in place of ${datasourceInclude} variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `war:inplace` to the list of goals executed for resource filtering in the Maven project configuration page.

**Right-click** on your project, then go to **Properties > Maven > Lifecycle Mapping** and add `war:inplace` to the **Goals to invoke on resource changes** as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, STS 2.7, m2eclipse and in this case tomcat 7 is now used internally, any other ideas why this isn't invoked or how to track down the problem?

Comment: upgraded to STS 2.8, with the new m2e support, filtering works great, right out of the box-

Answer (score 0):

Who's responsible for resolving the property/variable name in your Spring XML?  This is done at compile time via Maven or is it supposed to happen at runtime?  If at runtime, are you using Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`?

Comment: This is done at compile time by Maven. I have specified few maven profiles that loads resource bundle files that have values for variables.

Comment: Then how do you expect this to work when running from Eclipse?  Are you using a Maven plug-in in Eclipse, like M2E?

Comment: Yes, I am using Maven plugin M2E for Eclipse. My question is how to configure Eclipse to change the variables in spring-servlet.xml file before it is being loaded in Tomcat.